# Как увидеть ошибку при запуске docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```bsh
version: '3.0'

services:
   
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy 
    ports:
      - 81:80
    volumes:
      - /docker-projects/local-environment/proxy/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
```

Вот такой файл описывает настройку создаваемого контейнера. \

Я выполняю  запуск вот так:

```bsh
docker-compose up -d
```

Контейнер создается и завершает свою работу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я часто наблюдал такие проблемы.
При этом в консоль не выводится никаких ошибок и предупреждений.

Возможно проблема в файле **docker-compose.yml**

Как можно настроить вывод ошибок и предупреждений, чтобы понять, почему не запускается контейнер?

**Update_1**

Я отредактировал файл *.yml

```bsh
 volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

Контейнер запустился, но для чего тогда здесь Volumes, для меня загадка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увидеть ошибку в логе контейнера можно запустив `docker logs nginx-proxy` (если это тот же контейнер, что в конфиге, в чем я сомневаюсь).

Еще можно запускать `docker-compose up` без `-d`.

А сама ошибка возможно из-за того, что написано вместо
`- /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro` из инструкции.

---

В Windows работает виртуалка Linux (хост).

В этом Linux работает докер.

Докер предоставляет возможность взаимодействия с собой через `/var/run/docker.sock` на Linux-хост.

Контейнеру `proxy` нужно получать метаданные о соседних контейнерах от докера.

Вольюмы работают между Linux-хост и контейнером.

Иногда Linux-хост и Windows могут шарить fs, но это работает медленно и не стабильно.

Comment: /var/run/docker.sock - я так не могу написать, потому что у меня Windows

Comment: /docker-projects/ - это общая папка, расшаренная для docker default mashine

Comment: А пробовали? Насколько я понимаю, в Windows работает виртуалка Linux с докером.

Comment: Sergei Kirjanov . Что вы имеете ввиду , под "пробовал" ? Ведь символьна ссылка (/var/run/docker.sock ) указывает на директорию хостовой системы, где установлен Docker. Но в Windows файловая система совсем не такая как в Unix. Я именно должен указать путь к файлу в файловой системе Windows. Volumes нужны для того, чтобы сохранить нужные файлы, чтобы они не были  уничтожены вместе  с контейнером.

Comment: 1) doker у вас в линуксе. 2) это не символьна ссылка. 3) Volumes нужны для разных целей, и вашем случае не для этого

Comment: 4) даже если в другом случае нужно будет сохранить файлы, эффективней не давать к ним доступ из Windows, а использовать именованные вольюмы докера

Comment: ну так ведь это не рабочий проект, а проект для  удобства в  разработке мне. Volumes я использовал именно для того, чтобы например сохранить базу данных в моей файловой системе. тогда при уничтожении контейнера, данные сохраняются. А в данном случае, какой тогда смысл использовать  /var/run/docker.sock, какую роль он играет ? Он ведь должен как-то оказаться там по этому пути ?

Comment: Добавил описание; если помогло -- принимайте ответ.