# Ошибка создания volumes в Windows при развертывании nginx-procy

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

```bsh
version: '3.0'

services:
   
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy 
    ports:
      - 81:80
    volumes:
      - /docker-projects/local-environment/proxy/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
```

Вот такой файл описывает настройку создаваемого контейнера. \

Я выполняю  запуск вот так:

```bsh
docker-compose up
```

Контейнер создается и завершает свою работу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно, что он не может прочитать путь из Windows-системы.

**/docker-projects** - это общая папка, расшаренная для docker default mashine

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**.env**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```bsh
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

Как можно исправить данную проблему?

**Update_1**

Я отредактировал файл *.yml

```bsh
 volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

Контейнер запустился, но для чего тогда здесь **Volumes**, для меня загадка.
И на что влияют показанные ошибки ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И что, на винде у тебя по этому пути прямо вот лежит `docker.sock`?

Comment: даже в ошибке написано "/var/run/docker.sock" -- пробовали?

Comment: Да. Для этого и нужны Volumes. Ведь символьна ссылка (/var/run/docker.sock ) указывает на директорию хостовой системы, где установлен Docker. Но в Windows файловая система совсем не такая как в Unix. Я именно должен указать путь к файлу в файловой системе Windows. Volumes нужны для того, чтобы сохранить нужные файлы, чтобы они не были уничтожены вместе с контейнером

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174706/395779

Comment: это 2 смежных вопроса

Comment: а этот вопрос решен?

Comment: да, оба решены.